# Difference between return and return True in python

Tags: python

Whats the difference between return (without any value) and return True? Are both the same?

Comment: Return true is a boolean return, while return without any value causes your function to return back to your original function

Comment: [Python return statement reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not the same. The first will implicitly return `None`:

```
def f():
    return

print f() #None
```

while the second will return `True`:

```
def f():
    return True

print f() #True
```

**Note:** `True` and `False` are booleans in Python.

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not. `return` without any value returns (implicitly) `None`. `return True` on the other hand returns `True`.

`None` and `True` are not the same and in fact `bool(None)` is `False`.